# Octopus Runbook seems to ignore bash exit code

Tags: bash, syntax, octopus-deploy

I'm probably missing something obvious...

adding some light automation on simple post-deploy checks

but I am not able to get a failing exit code to fail the runbook run

What am I missing?

```
url=$(get_octopusvariable "SmokeTestURL")
statusCode=$(curl -X POST \
  --silent \
  --output /dev/null \
  --write-out "%{http_code}" \
  --header "accept: application/json" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data "..." \
  $url)
 
 echo $statusCode
 
 exitStatus=$(if [ $statusCode=200 ]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi)
 exit $exitStatus
```

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: spaces -- thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ $statusCode=200 ];
```

I think spaces are mandatory here. Also you should use quotes just in case $statusCode will be empty or contains spaces.

Also you can use shorter code:

```
[ "$statusCode" = "200" ] && exit 0 || exit 1
```